# How can i loop the above code?

Tags: vba, excel

```
Sub CalculateWFR()
        'select 1st sheet
        Worksheets(1).Activate

        'select range A:W
        Worksheets(1).Cells.Select
        Columns("A:W").Select

        'copy paste sheet programare in results
        Sheets("Programare").Range("A:W").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Range("A:W")

        'compare values from column U with column V and put +/-/= if value from U2 is higher,smaller or equals value from column V2
        Dim X As Integer Dim y As Integer
        X = Worksheets("Result").Range("U2").Value
        y = Worksheets("Result").Range("V2").Value

        If X > y Then
            Worksheets("Result").Range("X2") = "+"
        ElseIf X < y Then
            Worksheets("Result").Range("X2") = "-"
        ElseIf X = y Then
            Worksheets("Result").Range("X2") = "="
        End If
    End Sub
```

I am trying to loop the above code on column X, which has over 1000 Rows. Also there are no blank spaces. How can I do this?

Comment: Formatting hint: indent code with at least 4 spaces to make it show up as a code block.

Comment: Top google result (http://www.excel-easy.com/vba/loop.html). Please attempt doing it yourself first.

Answer (score 0):

As @Zerk suggested try to figure out how this works. 
Looping and Selecting is not required at all.
Try to think this as you were to put formula in column X and then google how to put that formula through VBA.

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Programare").Range("A:W").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Result").Range("A:W")
    Sheets("Result").Range("X2:X1000").Formula = "=IF(U2>V2,""+"",IF(V2>U2,""-"",IF(U2=V2,""="","""")))"
End Sub
```